# A circle has a diameter of 23 cm. How far from the center of the circle is a chord that is 5cm long?

Tags: geometry, circles

The answer can make use of trigonometry.

Comment: Welcome to Stackexchange. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my exercise, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context: What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc. Something to both show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: In fact, do you have to resolve it only by geometric-algebraic means or do you know trigonometry ? without knowing that it is difficult to help you.

Answer (score 1):

In the picture below, the cord is marked red. You know that the distance from $M$ (the center) to $B$ is equal to the radius, and so is the distance from $M$ to $X$. You also know the length of the chord, which is the distance between $B$ and $X$. If you take the chord as the base of a triangle, the distance from the center to the chord is simply the height of the triangle. Since you know the length of all sides of the triangle, you can use trigonometry to calculate that height.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the pythagorean theorem in that circle.
[image]

Comment: Very good picture.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the radius
of the circle
is $r$.

If the center of the circle
is at $O$,
and the chord
is of length $d$
with endpoints $A$ and $B$,
and the midpoint of
of the chord is at $C$,
then
$AC^2+CO^2 = AO^2$
(by good old Pythagorus)
so that
$(d/2)^2+CO^2 = r^2$
or
$CO^2
=r^2-(d/2)^2
$.

No trig is needed.